# Ionic 4 Multiple Errors when validating with Reactive Forms

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, frameworks

Im newbie with ionic and specially with ionic 4 which im using actually.

I was working on a register form and also a login. Everything it works great but when im validating and with the chrome console opened, it shows me a bunch of errors when the form is loaded.

The errors are :

ERROR TypeError: "_co.form is undefined"
ERROR CONTEXT 
Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 105, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…} }

However the form loads and i can input data, also the validation is working, it shows me the normal errors when a field is empty or incorrect. But this errors of chrome..., i also feel like they are lagging my app.

My code is this:

html:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>
        Registro
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

        <ion-content padding>
        <form (ngSubmit)="saveEntry()" [formGroup]="formgroup" >
            <!-- NOMBRE -->  
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="floating">Usuario</ion-label>
                <ion-input class="form-control" type="text"  formControlName="name" color="primary" ></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-label *ngIf="name.hasError('required') && name.touched" style="color:red;" padding>Nombre es requerido</ion-label>
              <!-- EMAIL -->  
              <ion-item>
                  <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
                  <ion-input type="email"  formControlName="email" color="primary"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-label *ngIf="email.hasError('required') && email.touched" style="color:red;" padding>Email es requerido</ion-label>              
              <!-- PASS 1  -->  
              <ion-item>
                  <ion-input [type]="passwordType" placeholder="Introduzca su contraseña" color="primary" formControlName="pass"></ion-input><ion-icon name="eye" item-right (click)="mostrarContrasenya(1)" [color]="colorOjo"></ion-icon>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-label *ngIf="pass.hasError('required') && pass.touched" style="color:red;" padding>Debe introducir la contraseña</ion-label>  
              <!-- PASS 2 -->  
              <ion-item>
                <ion-input [type]="passwordType2" placeholder="Repita su contraseña" color="primary" formControlName="pass2"></ion-input><ion-icon name="eye" item-right (click)="mostrarContrasenya(2)" [color]="colorOjo2"></ion-icon>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-label *ngIf="pass2.hasError('required') && pass2.touched" style="color:red;" padding>Debe introducir la segunda contraseña</ion-label>  

                <ion-list>
                  <ion-radio-group name="auto">
                    <ion-list-header>Sexo</ion-list-header>
                    <ion-item>
                      <ion-label>Masculino</ion-label>
                      <ion-radio value="masculino"></ion-radio>
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item>
                      <ion-label>Femenino</ion-label>
                      <ion-radio value="femenino"></ion-radio>
                    </ion-item>
                  </ion-radio-group>
                </ion-list>


              <div padding>
                  <ion-grid fixed>
                    <ion-row>
                      <ion-col size="6">
                          <ion-button size="large" expand="block" color="secondary" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Registrar</ion-button>
                      </ion-col>
                      <ion-col size="6">
                          <ion-button size="large" expand="block" color="medium" (click)="cancelar()">Cancelar</ion-button>
                      </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                  </ion-grid>

                </div>
            </form>
        </ion-content>
```

ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import {FormBuilder,FormGroup,AbstractControl,Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registro',
  templateUrl: './registro.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registro.page.scss'],
})
export class RegistroPage implements OnInit {

  passwordType:string = 'password';
  passwordShown:boolean=false;
  colorOjo:string = 'medium';

  passwordType2:string = 'password';
  passwordShown2:boolean=false;
  colorOjo2:string = 'medium';

  formgroup:FormGroup;
  name:AbstractControl;
  email:AbstractControl;
  pass:AbstractControl;
  pass2:AbstractControl;


  constructor(public navCtrl:NavController,public formbuilder:FormBuilder) {
    this.formgroup=formbuilder.group({
      name:['',Validators.required],
      //email:['',Validators.required]
      email: ['', Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
      ])],
      pass:['',Validators.required],
      pass2:['',Validators.required],
    });
    this.name=this.formgroup.controls['name'];
    this.email=this.formgroup.controls['email'];

    this.pass=this.formgroup.controls['pass'];
    this.pass2=this.formgroup.controls['pass2'];

  }



  ngOnInit() {
  }

  saveEntry(){
    alert("Suelta el torpedo loco");
  }
  cancelar(){
    this.navCtrl.goBack();
  }

  mostrarContrasenya(int:number){
    if(int == 1){
      if(this.passwordShown){
        this.passwordShown=false;
        this.passwordType='password';
        this.colorOjo='medium';
      }else{
        this.passwordShown=true;
        this.passwordType='text';
        this.colorOjo='primary';
      }
  }else{

    if(this.passwordShown2){
      this.passwordShown2=false;
      this.passwordType2='password';
      this.colorOjo2='medium';
    }else{
      this.passwordShown2=true;
      this.passwordType2='text';
      this.colorOjo2='primary';
    }
  }
}

}
```

also i would like to ask if it is possible to paint the input border if the input is invalid instead of letting it be blue as default.

Thanks for your time and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was there "[disabled]="!form.valid" i deleted it and is working properly. I would like to know now how i can change the color of the input border if it is invalid?